# Converting Normal Distribution to Lognormal distribution

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, math, normal-distribution, quantitative-finance

I have been following lectures of MIT open course on Application of Mathematics in Finance. I am trying to code out the concepts for better understanding.

According to lectures(from what I understand), if random variable X is normally distributed then exp(X) is log-normally distributed and vice versa (please correct me if I am wrong here).

Here is what I tried:

I have list of integers that are normally distributed:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

X = np.array(l)

mu = np.mean(X)
sigma = np.std(X) 

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(X, 35, density=True)
plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) 
),linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[Normally distributed curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkQ4U.png)

Now I want to get log-normal distribution from above data, here is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

X = np.array(l)
ln = []
for x in X:
    val = np.e**x
    ln.append(val)

X_ln = np.array(ln)
X_ln = np.array(X_ln) / np.min(X_ln)

mu = np.mean(X_ln)
sigma = np.std(X_ln) 

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(X_ln, 10, density=True)
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)

pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))

plt.plot(x, pdf, color='r', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Output :

[Not so clean Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN183.png)

I know there is a better way to do this, but I can't figure out how. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Here are couple of references:

[Log normal distribution in Python](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html)

[MIT lecture notes(topic-1.1)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_S096F13_lecnote3.pdf)

In case this is relevant, here is a list of elements I am trying to process:

[List of elements](https://drive.google.com/file/d/112yRSlEq_Tdgsl1mlOveKOKK00Vbhdc4/view?usp=sharing)

**Update 1:**

I have normalized X before adding values to **ln**. This fixed the distribution of histogram, however, I can't seem to fix to get red line to show log-normal distribution. Also the new histogram distribution is not very different from normal distribution. I can't think of any suitable reason for that.

This is the block of code I have added:

```
def normalize(v):
    norm=np.linalg.norm(v, ord=1)
    if norm==0:
        norm=np.finfo(v.dtype).eps
    return v/norm

X = np.array(l)
X = normalize(X)
```

New Output:

[Slightly better result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ntx.png)

Comment: On the whole it looks like you're heading in the right direction. Note that if you have numbers like 29.something or -19.something in your data, then `e**x` is going to turn those into extremely enormous or extremely minuscule numbers, and the histogram code is probably not going to handle that well. Can you normalize the data by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation? Try printing the values in `ln` before you get to the histogram and see if they look right.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you for this suggestion! I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I see the scale for the histogram is from 0 to 60. In order to put the histogram on the same scale as the red line for the pdf, remember that the pdf is normalized so that the area under the curve is 1, therefore the histogram must be normalized to 1 also. To get the normalizing factor, calculate the area under the curve for the histogram as it is now, then divide the points on the histogram by that factor. There might be an option to tell the histogram function to normalize it that way.